# Is it possible to change the OpenVPN server's virtual address client side only?

Tags: openvpn

I have multiple servers set up with the same OpenVPN server configuration. They have the same virtual subnets and virtual server addresses.

What I want is, that I need to connect to multiple servers simultaneously to ssh into them, without modifying any configuration on the servers. I don't care about conflicting subnets, I just need different IP addresses for each, while I need to work on them. I would like to give them an address before I connect to them from my PC(Windows/Linux).

Servers are being used by businesses I can't just change the virtual server address, whenever I need access to multiple at the same time.

I would like the ability to assign a different address for each server, from my PC, before I connect to them.

The only relevant config line on the servers is

```
server 10.0.0.0 255.255.255.0
```

No ifconfig line.

So every server has 10.0.0.1 as a virtual address. I would like to assign them *.1 *.2 *.3 etc. from my PC.

I could make a one time change on each server's configuration to enable this behavior.

I don't understand everything about the OpenVPN configuration, but after a lot of googling, I'm not sure if this is even possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one reason why many of us are so hot to get IPv6 deployed everywhere ASAP. You would not have this problem in IPv6 because everyone would have unique (global and/or local) addresses.

You can configure OpenVPN to serve an IPv6 ULA prefix, each of which is unique per server, without conflicting with any other existing network (IPv6 or IPv4). You can then connect and use the ULA network to perform your maintenance.